# Torch CrossEntropyCriterion error

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, torch, cross-entropy

I'm trying to train a simple test network on the XOR function in Torch. It works when I use MSECriterion, but when I try CrossEntropyCriterion it fails with the following error message:

```
/home/a/torch/install/bin/luajit: /home/a/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/THNN.lua:699: Assertion `cur_target >= 0 && cur_target < n_classes' failed.  at /tmp/luarocks_nn-scm-1-6937/nn/lib/THNN/generic/ClassNLLCriterion.c:31
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'v'
    /home/a/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/THNN.lua:699: in function 'ClassNLLCriterion_updateOutput'
    ...e/a/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/ClassNLLCriterion.lua:41: in function 'updateOutput'
    ...torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/CrossEntropyCriterion.lua:13: in function 'forward'
    .../a/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/StochasticGradient.lua:35: in function 'train'
    a.lua:34: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'dofile'
    /home/a/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:145: in main chunk
    [C]: at 0x00406670
```

I get the same error message when decomposing it into LogSoftMax and ClassNLLCriterion. Code is:

```
dataset={};
function dataset:size() return 100 end -- 100 examples
for i=1,dataset:size() do
  local input = torch.randn(2);     -- normally distributed example in 2d
  local output = torch.Tensor(2);
  if input[1]<0 then
      input[1]=-1
  else
      input[1]=1
  end
  if input[2]<0 then
      input[2]=-1
  else
      input[2]=1
  end
  if input[1]*input[2]>0 then     -- calculate label for XOR function
    output[2] = 1;
  else
    output[1] = 1
  end
  dataset[i] = {input, output}
end

require "nn"
mlp = nn.Sequential();  -- make a multi-layer perceptron
inputs = 2; outputs = 2; HUs = 20; -- parameters
mlp:add(nn.Linear(inputs, HUs))
mlp:add(nn.Tanh())
mlp:add(nn.Linear(HUs, outputs))

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyCriterion()
trainer = nn.StochasticGradient(mlp, criterion)
trainer.learningRate = 0.01
trainer:train(dataset)

x = torch.Tensor(2)
x[1] =  1; x[2] =  1; print(mlp:forward(x))
x[1] =  1; x[2] = -1; print(mlp:forward(x))
x[1] = -1; x[2] =  1; print(mlp:forward(x))
x[1] = -1; x[2] = -1; print(mlp:forward(x))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSE criterion was designed for regression problems. When it's used for classification tasks, the targets should be one-hot vectors. Cross entropy / Negative log likelihood criteria are used exclusively for classification; therefore, there's no need to explicitly represent the target class as a vector. In `torch` the target for such criteria is just an index of the assigned class (1 to the number of classes).

Comment: That makes sense, but how do you get the output to be such an index? Merely shrinking the number of outputs to one gives an error `attempt to index local 'input' (a number value)`.

Comment: @rwallace, you can get the indices of the max elements in each row somehow like that: `_, max_indexes = one_hot:max(2)`.